# How do I convert 021602 to be a date 02/16/02 in excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel 2010 spreadsheet with a column that has numbers which represent a specific date in the following format 021602, but I need to convert it to 02/16/2002.

Answer (score 1):

First convert your string to a good looking date, then use the datevalue function to turn it into an actual date.

```
=datevalue(left(a1,2)&"/"&mid(a1,3,2)&"/"&right(a1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

021602 is not a number, inside Excel, it is probably a string.

datevalue(), as it has already been pointed out, is region-depedent.

text() returns a string, but returning a date is usually a better practice.

if the input is K7, then:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(K7,2)+2000,MID(K7,LEN(K7)-3,2),LEFT(K7,2-6+LEN(K7)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`=text(date(right(a1,2),mid(a1,3,2),left(a1,2)),"mm/dd/yyyy")`

`Datevalue` depends on your system date setting. If your system is set to UK date format, you'll not be able to convert it successfully.